# ¿Cómo solucionar Target class [App\Http\Controllers\usuario] does not exist en Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

En mi `web.php` (fichero de rutas) tengo definido lo siguiente:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UsuarioController;
Route::resource('usuarios', App\Http\Controllers\UsuarioController::class);
```

En mi `UsuarioController` (controlador) tengo definido:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UsuarioController extends Controller
//Todo mi código
    public function show(usuario $usuario)
    {
        return view('usuarios.show', compact('usuario'));
    }
}
```

En mi `User.php` (modelo)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'user_type'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Comentarios a tener en cuenta:

1. El modelo User.php ha sido creado por Laravel (la autenticación automática de Laravel) y el controlador lo que he creado yo.
2. Siempre que me probado algún cambio para intentar dar solución a este problema, he limpiado la caché y las rutas con `php artisan route:clear` y `php artisan cache:clear`.
3. He leído un sinfín de posts, he probado todo lo que comentan en las respuestas pero no logro darle solución.[Ejemplo de cosas que probé](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8)
4. He probado agregar la línea  `protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';` en el fichero `RouteServiceProvider.php` y en el `AppServiceProvider.php`.
5. El error que recibo es `Target class [App\Http\Controllers\usuario] does not exist.` como si yo estuvier haciendo referencia al controlador usuario cuando nunca hago eso, siempre a UsuarioController.
6. He probado crear las rutas manualmente sin usar "resourse()" y tampoco funciona.

Sinceramente espero que me puedan ayudan. Creo que el problema está relacionado con que Laravel creó el modelo y yo el controlador, porque este error no lo recibo con ningún otro controlador / modelo.

Answer (score 1):

Vale, ya vi el problema:

```
public function show(user $usuario)
{
    return view('usuarios.show', compact('usuario'));
}
```

Esto explica el porqué funcionaba correctamente con el index, create y store, ya que, en ningún momento recibían un usuario por parámetro. Lo que debe recibir es un "user" no un "usuario".